# How to retrieve data from cloud using rest service

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

Our employee salary data are stored in the cloud provided by the third party. Currently, the third party  need to send us a copy of the database to us and we recover it to our local server for reporting purpose. I need to build a application to retrieve the data directly from the cloud and use the only tables we need for report purpose. the third party provide restful service to do this, but since I am new to web service programming, I am kind of lost here to decide what to do. So my question is what is the best way that i could proceed this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to start is to familiarize yourself with a coding language you'd like to use.  You can usually find documentation from the REST API provider on the 'developer' section of their website.  Once on their site, you can usually setup a developer sandbox account and grab a few quick examples from the documentation in the most popular languages i.e Java, PHP etc.  Then, using the documentation, tweak the example to get the data you want for your app.

It is common for REST APIs to assign you a key/token that you will use with each request.  Refer to their documentation for more examples.